# Exploding, un-nesting or flattening an array in Contour

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-contour

I have a dataset with a column of type `array`, and I would like to transform the dataset by exploding the array so that each row containing N array values is transformed into N rows, each containing a single value from the array in that column. Is this possible in Contour?

Answer (score 0):

This is done using the `explode` function in an Expression board, using syntax such as `explode(items_array)`.